# NullPointerException in Array Build from File

Tags: java, null, nullpointerexception, multidimensional-array

*The following code builds a "2D" `array` from strings in a text file.  At present it is returning a `NullPointException` error on the line:

> temp = thisLine.split(delimiter);
>   My question is, am I correct in understanding that `temp` is returning `null`?  If so, why, and how do I add a check for `null`?  I'm rather new to Java, and this is my first attempt at creating a string `array` of `arrays` from a file.*

**--------Edit--------**

**The above has been solved.**

For those interested below is the code returning a `IndexOutOfBoundsException.` Specifically the line:

> fileContents.set(i, fileContents.get(i).replace(hexLibrary[i][0], hexLibrary[i][1]));

```
System.out.println("SnR after this");

    String[][] hexLibrary;    // calls the replaces array from the LibToArray method
    hexLibrary = LibToArray();

    for(int i=0;i<502;i++){
        {
        fileContents.set(i, fileContents.get(i).replace(hexLibrary[i][0], hexLibrary[i][1]));
        }       
        }
    for (String row : fileContents) {
        System.out.println(row);        // print array to cmd
        }
```

---

***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

---

```
    public static String[][] LibToArray()
    {

        String thisLine;  
         String[] temp;  
         String delimiter=",";  
         String [][] hexLibrary = new String[502][2];  
    try
        {
            BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new FileReader("hexlibrary.txt"));  
            for (int j=0; j<502; j++) {  
                    thisLine=br.readLine(); 
                    temp = thisLine.split(delimiter);  
             for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {  
                hexLibrary[j][i]=temp[i];  
             }  
            }   
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {    // E.H. for try
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File not found.  Check name and directory."); // error message
        }
    return hexLibrary;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more likely that `thisLine` is `null`. That will happen if you run out of input before 502 lines are read. If `thisLine` is not `null`, then `thisLine.split(delimiter)` will not return `null`. You should always check for a `null` line:

```
for (int j=0; j<502; j++) {  
    thisLine=br.readLine(); 
    if (thisLine != null) {
        temp = thisLine.split(delimiter);  
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {  
            hexLibrary[j][i]=temp[i];  
        }  
    } else {
        // report error: premature end of input file
        break; // no point in continuing to loop
    }
}
```

Personally, I'd write your method to not assume any particular file length:

```
public static String[][] LibToArray() {
    List<String[]> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    String delimiter=",";  
    try (BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new FileReader("hexlibrary.txt"))) {
        String line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            String[] tmp = line.split(delimiter);
            // the next line is dangerous--what if there was only one token?
            // should add a check that there were at least 2 elements.
            lines.add(new String[] {tmp[0], tmp[1]});
            line = br.readLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File not found.  Check name and directory.");
    }
    String[][] hexLibrary = new String[lines.length][];
    lines.toArray(hexLibrary);
    return hexLibrary;
}
```

(The above uses the new Java 7 [try-with-resources syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). If you're using an earlier Java, you should add a `finally` clause that closes `br` before the method returns.

Comment: Your `null` check structure worked.  Now I've got an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` to deal with.

Comment: @InDeep - That's probably from a line that has no delimiters (and hence the array returned from `split` has fewer than 2 members).

Comment: it's a different section of code.  Specifically the search structure that uses this `array`.  I've added it in the OP if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking for end of the stream while reading the file.

Method `readLine` returns a `null` if the reader reaches end of the stream. You are hitting this point (`null`) in the first `for` loop (before it exits), depending on number of lines in the text file.

Answer (score 0):

If the first line (or any line) of hexlibrary.txt is empty or is not delimited by ","s, the String array returned by split() will probably be null. 
To check for that, just add an if-condition around your second for loop, something like this:
`if (temp == null) { /* your loop here */ }`

Comment: `split()` might return an empty array, but it will never return `null`.

Comment: A `NullPointerException` is thrown when an operation that needs to performed on an `object`, is performed on `null`. `temp` has nothing to do with the NPE in this case.